# Conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, noethers-theorem

> I have given one-dimensional motion of the particle directed
>   horizontally. A problem says: "*...Show that for this given motion
>   Conservation of Energy Law holds.*".

Since Energy can intuitively be thought of an operation that changes something over time, energy being conserved essentially means that the motion is not a function of time, but position only?

I.e. does energy conservation mean that a process is time-independent?

Comment: Kinetic Energy + Potential Energy = Constant

Comment: I know that, but how to show that it is constant?

Comment: What's the motion formula?

Comment: I will write text of a problem. **Air puck is moving on the smooth horizontal table and it is fixed on one end of a elastic spring with a constant stiffness factor $k$ and natural lenght $a$. Friction can be ignored. Show that for this movement Conservation of Energy Law holds.** By the Hooke's law, I have the force $F=-k(x-a)$. I got that potential energy is $V=\frac{1}{2}k(x-a)^2$. Kinetic energy is $m\dot r^2$

Comment: I've added the homework tag. For homework problems, please use the homework tag.

Comment: @BenCrowell Ok, I will. But I really don't know how to write homework problems anymore. The first problem I wrote in physics.SE, I tagged as a homework and I wrote what I have done. Then someone wrote this "It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.". When I posted another problem and tagged as a homework, someone required to write what I have done. I am a bit confused about how to behave on physics.SE

Comment: This is a nice solution: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Energy_Conservation_Mass_Spring_System.html

Comment: You can follow this wikipedia link you will find answer to your problem. All you need to prove that energy remain constant during the motion. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion

Look under energy of Simple harmonic motion.

Comment: @prask411: Actually, that was the OP's question. Energy conservation is ***defined*** as energy being constant. the question actually deals with noether's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that by Noether's theorem energy is conserved when the action is depednent on position only and not time. However, I think they want you to write down the equation of motion (use $F=ma$) and then use that to show that the total energy is a constant. Write down the expression for total energy and take its derivative w.r.t. time.